# Yii1 single login in mutlilingual site ( two domaines)

Tags: authentication, yii

I got two domains for a mutlilingual site :www.monsite.fr and www.mysite.com

they use the same app and same databas.

i made a htaccess redirection.

But when you log yourself in the www.monsite.fr you aren't logged in www.mysite.com .

How can i do to make the session cookie valid for both ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate domain just for your cookies i.e.:

```
cookie.monsite.com
```

Then you need to set proper cookie domain in your configuration (Yii 2 example):

```
// ...
'components' => [
    // ...
    'user' => [
        // ...
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_identity',
            'httpOnly' => true,
            'domain' => 'cookie.monsite.com',
        ],
    ],
    'session' => [
        // ...
        'cookieParams' => [
            'domain' => 'cookie.monsite.com',
            'httpOnly' => true,
        ],
    ],
    'request' => [ // optional
        // ...
        'csrfCookie' => [
            'domain' => 'cookie.monsite.com',
            'httpOnly' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: i should have precise i use yii1.1, i tried to add                                                        ` 'session' => array(
            'savePath' => '/some/writeable/path', // same for all 3 apps
            'cookieParams' => array(
                'domain' => 'http://www.monsite.fr',
            ),
        ),`

Comment: Was it ok? If not, have you tried to set domain `.monsite.fr` (starting with dot)?